# How to send multiple commands to xbee router in one data packet transmission using arduino uno

Tags: arduino, serial-port, xbee

I was wondering if I could control multiple IO pins on the xbee remotely with one command from a coordinator.

I can easily send one IO pin high or low as below

```
xB.write((byte)0x7E);
xB.write((byte)0x0);
xB.write((byte)0x10);
xB.write((byte)0x17);
xB.write((byte)0x0);  // Frame ID
xB.write((byte)0x00); // first byte
xB.write((byte)0x13); // 2
xB.write((byte)0xA2); // 3
xB.write((byte)0x00); // 4
xB.write(addy5); // 5
xB.write(addy6); // 6
xB.write(addy7); // 7
xB.write(addy8);// 8
xB.write((byte)0xFF);
xB.write((byte)0xFE);
xB.write((byte)0x02);
xB.write('D');
xB.write('0');
xB.write(val);
long sum = 0x17 + 0x13 + 0xA2 + addy5 + addy6 + addy7 + addy8 + 0xFF + 0xFE + 0x02 + 'D' + '0' + val;
xB.write((byte)0xFF - (sum & 0xFF));
```

But I can't seem to send more than one digital pin change at once like this.

```
xB.write((byte)0x7E);
xB.write((byte)0x0);
xB.write((byte)0x1F);
xB.write((byte)0x17);
xB.write((byte)0x0);  // Frame ID
xB.write((byte)0x00); // first byte
xB.write((byte)0x13); // 2
xB.write((byte)0xA2); // 3
xB.write((byte)0x00); // 4
xB.write(addy5); // 5
xB.write(addy6); // 6
xB.write(addy7); // 7
xB.write(addy8);// 8
xB.write((byte)0xFF); // "10"67
xB.write((byte)0xFE);// 10"66"
xB.write((byte)0x02);

xB.write('D');
xB.write('1');
xB.write(bin[0]);

xB.write('D');
xB.write('0');
xB.write(bin[1]);

xB.write('D');
xB.write('2');
xB.write(bin[2]);

xB.write('D');
xB.write('3');
xB.write(bin[3]);

xB.write('D');
xB.write('5');
xB.write(bin[4]);

xB.write('D');
xB.write('4');
xB.write(bin[5]);

long sum = 0x17 + 0x13 + 0xA2 + addy5 + addy6 + addy7 + addy8 + 0xFF + 0xFE + 0x02 + 'D' + '1' + bin[0] + 'D' + '0' + bin[1] + 'D' + '2' + bin[2] + 'D' + '3' + bin[3] + 'D' + '5' + bin[4] + 'D' + '4' + bin[5];
xB.write((byte)0xFF - (sum & 0xFF));
```

What might I be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the API reference for the [Remote AT Command Frame](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90002002/Default.htm#Reference/r_frame_0x17.htm), the bytes after the command (`D0`) are the value for that command.  The XBee module doesn't have a frame type for multiple AT commands, but you can send a series of queued commands, and have them all apply at once when you set the "Apply Changes" bit of the `options` field.

So, where you're sending `0x02` right before the AT command, you would send `0x00` for the commands you want to queue up, and only send the `0x02` on the last command to have it apply all changes at once.

Also, consider writing some routines to simplify your frame sending.  For example, a single function that takes a pointer to a buffer with a length could automatically send the start of frame (`0x7E 0x00 <length>`) and a calculated checksum byte at the end of the frame.

Comment: Awesome, tried it out, and that is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked!  Please mark this answer as "accepted" since it worked for you, that way others searching on SO will know it's an answered question.

Comment: Marked it as answered, but can't give upvotes due to lack of votes myself. Boo.